# change session length dynamically by role in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, session, razor-pages, usermanager

I need to give different session length to users according to a certain role.
Since session length is configured in program.cs I tried to check the role in it.
The problem that in order to us IsInRole(...)  function I need to know who is the current user which I don't.
Is it possible to do it like that?
Any other way to do it?

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: That what chat GPT suggested:
 // Retrieve the current user by their unique identifier (e.g., email)
            var adminUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@example.com").Result;

            // Check if the admin user exists and belongs to the "admin" role
            if (adminUser != null && userManager.IsInRoleAsync(adminUser, "admin").Result)
            {
                // The current user is an admin, perform necessary actions
                // You can set a flag or store this information for later use
            }
but he wants me to provide the unique identifier...

Comment: It is not possible to configure session timeouts by role or user. You can only set it for the application.